# Error "Invalid frame header" when send data from client to server - Python websocket

Tags: javascript, python, python-2.7, websocket

I have an issue when send data from client to server - Python websocket.
Here my client code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var s = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8999');
    s.onopen = function (e) {
        console.log("Socket opened.");
    };
    s.onclose = function (e) {
        console.log("Socket closed.");
    };
    s.onmessage = function(t){alert(t)};
    function onSubmit() {
        s.send("Hello from client");
    }
</script>
```

And server - Python code:

```
import socket
import re
from base64 import b64encode
from hashlib import sha1

websocket_answer = (
    'HTTP/1.1 101 Switching Protocols',
    'Upgrade: websocket',
    'Connection: Upgrade',
    'Sec-WebSocket-Accept: {key} \r\n\r\n',
)

GUID = "258EAFA5-E914-47DA-95CA-C5AB0DC85B11"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('127.0.0.1', 8999))
s.listen(10)

client, address = s.accept()
text = client.recv(1024)

print "Get data text from client and send back this data: "
print text

key = (re.search('Sec-WebSocket-Key:\s+(.*?)[\n\r\r\n]+', text)
    .groups()[0]
    .strip())

response_key = b64encode(sha1(key + GUID).digest())
response = '\r\n'.join(websocket_answer).format(key=response_key)

client.send(response)

clientData = client.recv(4096)
client.send("Hello from server")
```

When run Python Socket Server, I can connect from client, it mean  "console.log("Socket opened.");" is working.
But when I send data from client to server by running function onSubmit() data, I get the error "Invalid frame header" in console log of Chrome develop tool.
And when I debug data from client sent to server (clientData variable in Python file), I got an crack string: "��Ϭ����Ջ��ߕ������܉�".
Anybody can help me to resolve this problem?